# For what values of $\alpha$ does this integral converge?

Tags: calculus

For what real values of $\alpha$ does this integral converge?

$$\int_0^\infty {x^\alpha e^{-x} dx}$$

And what's the usual approach to this kind of problem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: @Jack: But my textbook says it's only convergent when $\alpha>-1$, which differs with what Wikipedia says ($\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Z}_{(-\infty,-1]}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:
$$\frac{1}{e} \int_0^1 {x^\alpha dx}<\int_0^1 {x^\alpha e^{-x} dx} <\int_0^1{x^\alpha  dx} $$
Thus, $\int_0^1 {x^\alpha e^{-x} dx}$ converges iff  $\int_0^1{x^\alpha  dx}$ does which happens for $\alpha>-1$.
$ \int_1^\infty {x^\alpha  e^{-x}dx} < \int_1^\infty {x^\alpha ( x^N/N!)^{-1} dx}$ (where $N>\alpha +2$) does always converge.

Comment: But why in the Gamma Function article wikipedia says that it can also be defined at all points except $\mathbb{Z}_{(-\infty,-1]}$?

Comment: Wikipedia says that you can continue the function defined by this to an analytical function defined everywhere except on the negative integers but not that the integral itself converges everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $\alpha > -1$, there exists $X(\alpha)$ such that $x^{\alpha} e^{-x} \leq e^{-x/2}$ for all $x > X(\alpha)$.

Hence, $$\int_0^{\infty} x^{\alpha} e^{-x} dx \leq \int_0^{X(\alpha)} x^{\alpha} e^{-x} dx + \int_{X(\alpha)}^{\infty} e^{-x/2} dx = \underbrace{\int_0^{X(\alpha)} x^{\alpha} e^{-x} dx}_{< \infty} + 2e^{-X(\alpha)/2}$$

For $\alpha \leq -1$, the integral diverges, which can be shown as follows. Let $\alpha = -1-\beta$
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^{\alpha} e^{-x} dx = \underbrace{\int_0^{\epsilon} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x^{1+\beta}} dx}_{I} + \underbrace{\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x^{1+\beta}} dx}_{II}$$
Note that $$II \leq \displaystyle \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \dfrac1{x^{1+\beta}} dx < \infty$$
Note that $$I \geq \int_0^{\epsilon} \dfrac{e^{-\epsilon}}{x^{1+\beta}} dx = \infty$$
Hence, the integral converges for $\alpha > 1$ and diverges for $\alpha \leq -1$.

The integral you are interested in, wherever it converges, is called the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). The Gamma function is defined for $\alpha \leq -1$ as well through analytic continuation of the above integral. However, the Gamma function still has poles (blows to $\infty$) at negative integers.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the interval into $[0,1] \cup (1,\infty)$.

In $(1,\infty)$, $e^x$ dominates $x^{\alpha}$ as $x \to \infty$, so $\int_1^\infty {x^\alpha e^{-x} dx}$ is convergent for all $\alpha$. (To make this precise: given $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, we can find $x_0$ such that $x^{\alpha} < e^{x/2}$ for all $x \ge x_0$. So $0 \le x^{\alpha}e^{-x} \le e^{-x/2}$ for all $x \ge x_0$, and the integral converges because the integral of $e^{-x/2}$ converges.)

And in $[0,1]$, $0.3 < e^{-x} \le 1$, so the convergence of the integral is determined only by the convergence of $\int_0^1 {x^\alpha dx}$, which you can work out for yourself.